# Pick substrings from a input string

Tags: c++, string, stringstream

I have a given requirement where valid input formats of a string are -:

```
- USD/AGR
- USDAGR
- +USD+AGR
- -USD+AGR
- -USD-AGR
- +USD-AGR
- +USD+AGR
- +USD/AGR
- -USDAGR
- -USD/AGR 
- USD-AGR

and so on...
```

Inputs are in stringstream data type:
Where '+' means to include this string for further calculation which is not the part of this program and '-' is not to include this string.

I have to pick USD , AGR i.e. substring from the given string which is given as stream input. I have tried the below code, but it's failing in some cases. Please suggest a correction (note USD and AGR could be replaced with any 3 char like INR/JPY).

// Example program

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <sstream>  
#include <stdio.h> 
#include <algorithm>

using namespace std;
#define CCY_LEN 3
int main()
{
    stringstream ss;
    string ss1 = "USD/SAR" , ss2;

    ss1.erase(std::remove(ss1.begin(), ss1.end(), '/'), ss1.end());

    cout<<ss1<<endl;

    ss.str(ss1);

    while(!ss.eof())
    {
        ss2.clear();
        ss.width(CCY_LEN+1);
        ss >> ss2;

        if(!ss2.size())
            break;
        if(ss2.at(0) == '-'){
            cout <<" 1 " <<ss2.substr(1, CCY_LEN)<<endl ;
        }
        if(ss2.at(0) == '+'){
            ss2.erase(std::remove(ss2.begin(), ss2.end(), '+'), ss1.end());
            cout << " 2 " << ss2.substr(0, CCY_LEN) <<endl;
        }
        else{
            cout << " 3 " <<ss2.substr(0, CCY_LEN )<<endl ;
        }
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: I've removed the `array` tag since I don't see any and the question does not mention, and I've added the `c++` tag as the language tag is important for both syntax coloring of code and for persons who know the language to be able to more easily find your question.

Comment: Thanks crashmstr

Comment: +,- and / are just special character,I am giving you an example suppose i have transaction in many currencies and user want to list only USD and INR so he can give input as - USDINR or USD/INR or +USD/+INR or +USD+INR all are valid input.

Comment: + is just to include this currency and - means not to list those with minus as leading character and / as of no meas it just given a way of input use slash between or not .   we can give input like only -INR so it will list all currency except INR

Comment: @RyanVincent thanks